# how to create a animal list in java

Tags: java, arraylist, polymorphism

```
    public class Animaltestdrive{
    public static void main(String args[]){
     MyanimalList list=new MyanimalList();
     Dog a=new Dog();
     Cat c=new Cat();
     list.add(a);
     list.add(c);
 }}
public class MyanimalList{
    private Animal[] animals = new Animal[5];
    private int nextIndex=0;

    public void add(Animal a){
        if(nextIndex< animals.length){
            animals[nextIndex]=a;
            System.out.println("Animal added at " + nextIndex);
            nextIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

i want this modified so it should give the output:
Animal added at 0
Animal added at 1

Comment: What is the problem with the given code? What does it currently output?

Comment: Please post [mcve] so we don't have to guess what is `MyanimalList list=new MyanimalList();`  for and what does `public class MyanimalList Animal{`  this mean (it will not compile)

Comment: @c0der i copied the code from head first java..and i just began learning oop..this is surely something easy but i cant figure it out..can you please have a look in page no 207 in the link below..thank you https://books.google.lk/books?id=KXQrAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA208&lpg=PA208&dq=how+to+create+a+animal+list+in+java&source=bl&ots=WN0li_DDGo&sig=9d1ShydHmiMzR7wpTaELC26ZUS0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMjLCq7unbAhVXSX0KHXfyCvIQ6AEIXzAE#v=onepage&q=how%20to%20create%20a%20animal%20list%20in%20java&f=false

Comment: @NicoHaase it doesnt even compile..

Comment: If it does not compile you probably sis not copy it properly or completely. If the question is **how to create a animal list** : it is already created in `main`. BTW: Head First post their code on line.

Comment: @c0der only thing i did was copied the code and pasted...i didnt create any cat,dog or animal class and didnt inherit any class...im new to this stuff..can you please add the required classes and inheritance..

Comment: No, but you can do it and post questions when you have problems.

Comment: @Lakindu Wickramaratne Are you still looking for an answer?